# Печать BLOB поля с проверкой

Tags: delphi

Как в delphi из блоб поля вытащить все сразу на печать?

Comment: Вопрос из серии как сделать, то не зная что.

Что у Вас в BLOB ?

Comment: "с проверкой" чего?

Comment: С начало проверить что там а потом решить печатать или нет
и мне не нужны вопросы на мой вопрос мне нужен код

Comment: Как решается моя проблема я знаю но не знаю как это объяснить машине а точнее как это выразить в коде

Comment: Конечный набор форматов данных известен? Их существует огромное множество.

Comment: Конечно. все данные возможно напечатать но мне больше присуща идея сначала выгрузить все в файл

Comment: Во общем так как я первый раз здесь просто вопрос насущный объясняю всю ситуацию. множество текстовых документов каких как PDF, doc, doxc, txt и так далие сохраняю в базу в блоб после чего нужно без лишних вопросов вывести на печать. в базу в отдельное поле сохраняю расширение, имя , и размер документа.

Comment: Как это сделать мне нужен код delphi

Answer (score 1):

> Как в delphi из блоб поля вытащить все
> сразу на печать?

Вашу задачу следует разбить на две.

1.Как в delphi из блоб поля вытащить все сразу?

Воспользуйтесь методом TBlobField.SaveToStream для сохранения данных в поток.

2.Как в delphi отправить на печать?

Эта задача решается исходя их характера данных, которые лежали в блобе (а теперь уже в потоке). Текст? Картинка? Вордовский документ? Просто набор байт?

Comment: А как программно определить что в блобе и соответственно печатать

Comment: Никак. вы должны четко представлять, что у вас там лежит. Можно попытаться определить популярные форматы файлов (BMP, JPG, PNG, DOC и т.п.) по сигнатуре. Но форматов данных очень много, в том числе закрытых. Если вы не знаете, что там, то где гарантия что это не набор структурированных записей например?